# Correct way to work on roles

Tags: django

My system has two kinds of users - student and employee. Both students and employees have some common (authenticated) pages. But both of them have their unique pages.

How can we do this in Django?

I can do this. But I want to know the correct way.

Answer (score 1):

I would make a django group for each role, add users appropriately, and then use the [`GroupRequiredMixin`](http://django-braces.readthedocs.org/en/latest/access.html#grouprequiredmixin) from [django-braces](http://django-braces.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) to manage the permission check.

I don't think there is a 'correct way', just different solutions which match different scenarios.